# Removing string chunks that are not attached to relevant text in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Any set of characters that are not attached to a-zA-Z0-9 need to be removed. Examples:

- This is great! *(nothing to do here)*
- Yes, this is also ok!? *(nothing to do here)*
- This, is !!! not great. !!!!!!! **-->** This, is not great. *(chunks detected)*
- Too much wasted periods ...... right? **-->** Too much wasted periods right? *(chunks detected)*
- ....{{..... chunks are at the start **-->** chunks are at the start *(chunks detected)*
- chunks are at the end [[]] **-->** chunks are at the end *(chunks detected)*
- hello [[[[[[]]]]]] friend.....? how are you [}}}}}} **-->** hello friend.....? how are you  *(chunks detected)*

Chunks are considered any stand alone character or string that are:

- different than a-zA-Z0-9
- at any position (start, middle, end)
- are not in touch with any alphanumeric characters in any way

Comment: And what have you tried? I suppose "stand alone", "attached" and "in touch" all refer to separation by any kind of whitespace?

Comment: From your question now, it looks like this line is ok and should have no replacement: `This is great!` and this one should have replacement: `This is great!!`  And the following one is ok and should have no replacement too: `This is great!?!?!?`

Comment: @m.buettner exactly. Separation in both sides, or just left or just right.

Comment: @動靜能量 exactly, the first two examples have no chunk at all.

Comment: You're requirements and your samples don't match. For example: The `?` should be removed from `Yes, this is also ok!?` as it is *not in touch with any alphanumeric characters*. Conversely, *extra* spaces should remain as they are *in touch* with alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). We can simply match as many non-word, non-space characters as possible, and then assert that there is no non-space character next to the chunk:

```
$output = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)[^a-z\d\s]+(?!\S)/i', '', $input);
```

Note, that this will may leave multiple whitespace characters (the ones to the left and to the right of a chunk). If you don't want that, it is probably easiest to run a second replacement step:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($output));
```

Comment: doesn't work in this case: `hello [[[[[[]]]]]] friend.....? how are you [}}}}}}` it should return `hello friend.....? how are you` the 5 periods are in deed touching valid alphanumeric. Your code returns `hello friend. how are you`

Answer (score 1):

*A* regular expression that matches 1 or more non alphanumeric characters not *touching* a valid character.

```
/(^| )[^a-zA-Z0-9]+( |$)/
```

PHP usage:

```
preg_replace('/(^| )[^a-zA-Z0-9]+( |$)/', '$1$2', $item);
```

**Note:** You will notice some extra spaces when running against your input. Technically these spaces are *touching* a valid character.

Comment: I think this will also capture a series of whitespace characters.  Should you add `\s` to the negative character class?

Comment: in deed, it is capturing whitespaces. it works alright, but the spaces are being altered :s

Comment: Technically this is correct. That is to say it matches the requirements. It's your code samples that don't. See my comment on your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
'/(?:(?<=\s)|^)[^a-z0-9]+(?:(?=\s)|$)/i'
```

http://codepad.org/2JZLHdhL

The basic thought is:  use a lookbehind to assert we either have white space behind us, or are at the beginning of the string.  Then capture non alphanumeric characters, and use a lookahead to enforce that it is followed white space or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you will need

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\d\s:]+[^a-zA-Z0-9\d\s:]
```

This will only pick up any none alphanumeric characters that are not attached to an alphanumeric character

Comment: This would cause problems for chunks at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: btw \d is the same as 0-9 so either of them can be excluded from both sections of the regex.

Comment: @JasonBruce I don't think so. This will simply match any block of at least two non-letter, non-digit, non-whitespace, non-colon characters, no matter where they are found.